How do you get the name of a picture placed in a cell by Excel's new "Place in Cell" feature
There are several posts here, and elsewhere that suppose to answer the question, "How do you get the name of a picture placed in a cell by Excel's new 'Place in Cell' feature?" This apparently differs from the "Picture.Insert(path)" method.
Both of the methods suggested (as shown in the following code) reveal nothing. There may be minor errors in them, but they have be changed many times to try to a picture's NAME or EXISTENCE.
Apparently this code may work when the Picture is placed OVER the cell. However, each time this happens the name changes to something like "Picture ##". I would like to count all of the inserted images AND get a static name (or at least evidence of it's presence in a cell.)
FYI, the worksheet is Unprotected when running the code.
Public Function GetPictureName() As String
' Return the name of the Picture in the current cell
Dim shp As Shape

    GetPictureName = vbNullString

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.address = ActiveCell.address Then
            GetPictureName = shp.Name
        End If
    Next

End Function


Public Function Is_PictureInCell() As Boolean
' Is there a picture in the current cell
Dim pic As Picture

    Is_PictureInCell = False

    For Each pic In Sheets(1).Pictures
        If pic.TopLeftCell.address = ActiveCell.address Then Is_PictureInCell = True
        If InStr(1, pic.Name, "Picture") > 0 Then Debug.Print pic.Name
    Next
    
End Function

Both of these functions have been changed to look for "Pictures" and "Shapes" with no success when the Picture is in the cell. Although I could use the "old" insert method I am trying to future-proof my code by using Office 365 features.

It appears that there isn't an in-cell picture object in the Excel object model yet. It is not part of the Shapes or Pictures collections, and I'm not sure if it even has a name like a regular shape object.
Here is a workaround script to detect in-cell picture in a cell. It may not be perfect, but hopefully, it offers some useful ideas.
Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print IIf(HasPicInCell(c), "Found", "No") & " pic-in-cell in " & c.Address
End Sub

' Argument rCell is a single cell, modify as needed
Function HasPicInCell(rCell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim ShpCnt As Long, Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = rCell.Parent
    ShpCnt = Sht.Shapes.Count
    ' pic in cell >> pic over cells, it is the last shape object
    rCell.PlacePictureOverCells
    If Sht.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
        HasPicInCell = False
    Else
        HasPicInCell = (ShpCnt < Sht.Shapes.Count)
        ' get the last shape
        Dim Shp: Set Shp = Sht.Shapes(Sht.Shapes.Count)
        ' Excel 365 [Version 2411 (Build 18210.20000)] crashes without the following line.
        ' I'm not sure if this is a bug in the version or an issue with my PC.
        ActiveCell.Select
        ' ***
        Shp.Select
        ' pic over cells >> pic in cell
        Shp.PlacePictureInCell
    End If
End Function

If Alt Text of pic-in-cell is not used in your file, the function may be simplified as below.
' Argument rCell is a single cell, modify as needed
Function HasPicInCell(rCell As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    rCell.UpdatePictureInCellAlternativeText ""
    HasPicInCell = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function



The point about the lack of a property (at least one that is documented) on the PictureInCell object was helpful. As was the us of the Alt Text. The only way I can find to get this alt text is by looking at the Formula property, it shows up there(?)

Yes. Hopefully, Microsoft will implement more properties / methods for the picture-in-cell object in the future.

We can get the cells like this:
Function GetCellsWithPictures(ws As Worksheet) As Collection
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Map As New Collection
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ws.UsedRange
        If Cell.HasRichDataType And Cell.Formula = "Picture" Then Map.Add Cell
    Next
    
    Set GetCellsWithPictures = Map
End Function

The pictures appear to be stored as data and do not have names.  Two cells with the same image data will be equal.  I tested this with two workbooks using copies of the same image with different names.

It is interesting how the formula shows text, but you cannot set it to text that is retrievable.

My workaround (thanks to you, taller) is to use the cell's alt text to store a ID tag and the path of the image. This can then be read as the cell's formula property. I can count the images by looping through a range and looking for my ID tag using instr and can have the path and filename (extracted from the path) as needed.
When a picture is placed OVER a cell, I save the name which shows up as a shape (only while placed over cells). I use that saved name to place the picture back in the same cell:
ActiveSheet.Shapes(SavedName).PlacePictureInCell

Until we have better developer docs and more object properties, this will be OK.
